# Which clustering algorithm is suitable for clustering geographical locations?

Tags: cluster-analysis, clustering-key

I am developing an application which works similar to Tinder. I am guessing Tinder groups closest results by running clustering algorithm.
In my application have to similarly group data based on geographical location. I might have to run clustering based on many inputs, so it has to be efficient. Please suggest suitable algorithm for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to group or cluster for a Tinder-like use case:

- it's too expensive
- it's too static
- it does not add value (you can't just present a cluster to the user)

What you want to use is **similarity search**. Find other users that are a) nearby, b) recently online, c) have some interests in common, d) have not been recently shown.

Answer (score 0):

For somebody who is looking for similar solution, There is a good answer about fast similarity search algoritms on quora https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-fast-similarity-search-algorithms-and-data-structures-for-high-dimensional-vectors/answer/Raghavendran-Balu?srid=hYuT

I found R-tree to be most suited for my application. There is a good github project for R-tree https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree